# MPMovieplayercontroller buffer state and pause while streaming

Tags: ios, video, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am making a video play application which plays videos on my server. I initiate the application through the below code.

```
    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://download1.mp4mobilemovies.net/Bollywood/Baahubali%20-%20The%20Beginning%20-%20DvdScr/Baahubali%20-%20The%20Beginning%20-%20DvdScr%20-%201.mp4")!

    self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming
    self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    self.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
    self.moviePlayer.stop()
    self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(self.moviePlayer.view)
    self.moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
    self.moviePlayer.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
    self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
    self.moviePlayer.play()
```

Even I have a HUD which starts making a progress indicator when the view did appear and there I also set two notification object to see the playbackstatechange of video as well as load state of movie. Playback state change is working good. Video starts playing and after some time it goes to pause state and load state does not change to STALLED or UNKNOWN so that I would know that this is a buffer state. Please advice how to handle the buffering state and autoplay when buffer finish

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "videoCanPlay:", name: MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playbackchanged:", name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

func videoCanPlay(notification: NSNotification){
    var moviePlayerController = notification.object
        as! MPMoviePlayerController
    if(self.moviePlayer?.loadState == MPMovieLoadState.Playable)
    {
       // let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
       // UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
      //  NSLog("Play");
        MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
    }
```

///These state does not get called

```
    if(self.moviePlayer?.loadState == MPMovieLoadState.Stalled)
    {
        NSLog("stalled");
    }

     if (self.moviePlayer?.loadState == MPMovieLoadState.Unknown)
    {
        NSLog("unknown");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to check if player is buffering:

```
self.moviePlayer?.playableDuration
```

I not tested the answer, but I think that if playableDuration is 0 then player is currently buffering